# Getting a Maximum call stack size exceeded when building library package using Angular 12

Tags: angular, npm, error-handling, callstack

When adding export of my module in public-api.ts the Angular compiler throws a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" which dont tell my the cause of the error. Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?
I have other library packages running lower Angular version and they are using this type of export declaration and are building as expected.

Log output:

[error] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at parseTag (C:\g\PrimeNGComponents\logicmedia-primes-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:34788:35)
at C:\g\PrimeNGComponents\logicmedia-primes-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:34619:44
at Object.scanRange (C:\g\PrimeNGComponents\logicmedia-primes-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:11543:26)
at parseJSDocCommentWorker (C:\g\PrimeNGComponents\logicmedia-primes-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:34592:32)
at C:\g\PrimeNGComponents\logicmedia-primes-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:34548:91
at doInsideOfContext (C:\g\PrimeNGComponents\logicmedia-primes-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:29343:30)
at Object.parseJSDocComment (C:\g\PrimeNGComponents\logicmedia-primes-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:34548:31)
at C:\g\PrimeNGComponents\logicmedia-primes-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:29162:123
at Object.mapDefined (C:\g\PrimeNGComponents\logicmedia-primes-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:806:30)
at addJSDocComment (C:\g\PrimeNGComponents\logicmedia-primes-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:29162:28)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
It came down to, that all module packages in my module must also be in inner package.json file. This was not obvious from the error log.